# Network path of a file/directory using Java

Tags: java, windows, file, file-sharing, file-properties

How to get the network path of a file or directory on a windows pc using java? Usually we can see it in shared folder's properties on windows. As shown below.....
[image]

Comment: Get it, given what - what's the input?

Comment: @Ed-Staub I want to input the file path such as "E:\"

Answer (score 2):

Using Java you can pass `net SHARE` command in `exec` method of `Runtime` class and then parse the outputstream from the `Process` class to get the corresponding Network Path of your directory. The output of `net SHARE directory_name` command is as follows:

```
Share name        Share
Path              C:\Share
Remark
Maximum users     No limit
Users
Caching           Manual caching of documents
Permission        user, FULL
```

You need to get the value of the Path key from the above output. Following is the pseudo-code of how you can achieve this:

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net SHARE directory_name");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    String line;

    while (null != (line = reader.readLine())) {
        writer.write(line);
    }

    System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: Now it is running with no error, but where should I put the input directory? Does this work on Windows? I am trying with -- Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net SHARE E:\\"); with no luck. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The API to call is [WNetEnumResource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192689). You need to use JNI to call Windows APIs. An example can be found at http://public.m-plify.net/sourcecode/.